# LMS7002M: I & Q DATA formats from LIMESDR

Tags: intel-fpga, sdr

Can any one tell me what is the data format of LMS7002m I & Q sample? Are they unsigned int or floating or double? how are they ?
Also kindly anyone show me any hint of proof for their answer....

LMS7002M is a chip from LIMEMicrosystem for RF application used popularly in LIMESDR-USB board.

[Datasheet available here](https://limemicro.com/app/uploads/2017/07/LMS7002M-Data-Sheet-v3.1r00.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It's only 12 bits so it can't be any standard floating-point format. I think the tables in the "LIMELIGHT™ DIGITAL IQ DATA INTERFACE" section of the datasheet give you the rest of the answer....read carefully.

Comment: The table talks about DAC & ADC not necessarily the final outputs !!! therein lies my doubt

Comment: no, that's not how I read that table.

Comment: marcus muller are you mentioning me.  because tables have that heading

Comment: Reading is key. "*Following the ADCs, the signal
conditioning is performed by the digital Transceiver Signal Processor
(TSP) and the resulting signals are then provided to the BB via the
LimeLightTM digital IQ interface.*" The "BB" is your application logic, @ARKARUP7304.

Comment: correct. TSP comes in the game. whether or not it is getting modified there or not? whether or not the data is getting modified in the LimeLightTM digital IQ interface that is my concern and questiion.